# Histogram using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I'm trying to do a histogram in gnuplot, but I don't want my bins to have fixed width. I need the width of a bin to respect the actual width of the interval.
Also, I'm not really sure what to put in the data file or how to organize it.
Can someone help me with doing this?
I need the graph to look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9KqC.png)

Comment: Can you please share a sample of the input data, too?

Comment: What is your "actual width of the interval"? If you don't want the bins with fixed width, but how do you want the width to be set? And how many bins do you want?

Comment: Still interested in an answer? Then please respond to the comments. Otherwise I would suggest to delete this question.